# compile error in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flashdevelop

I have this code written in ActionScript 3 :

```
private function _initializeUI() {
        function onClick(e : Event) {
            var checkBox : CheckBox = CheckBox(e.target);
            Chat.sendToClient("checkBox pressed : " + checkBox.name);
            switch(checkBox.name) {
                case "autoHealCheckBox":
                    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
                    _settings.walle.autoHeal = checkBox.checked;
                    break;
                case "autoOffCheckBox":
                    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
                    _settings.walle.autoOff = checkBox.checked;
                    break;
                case "autoBattleCheckBox":
                    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
                    _settings.walle.autoBattle = checkBox.checked;
                    break;
                case "debugCheckBox":
                    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
                    _settings.walle.debug = checkBox.checked;
                    break;
                case "onOffCheckBox":
                    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
                    if (checkBox.checked) {
                        this.start();
                    } else {
                        this.stop();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if (checkBox.name.substr(0, 6) == "PickUp") {
                        checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
                        var k : String = checkBox.name.substr(6).split('_').join(' ');
                        _settings.walle.pickup[k] = checkBox.checked;
                    }
                    break;
            };
        }
```

when i compile FlashDevelop say

```
src/walle/Walle.as:113: characters 11-18 : parse error Unexpected onClick
```

what should I do?

Comment: What is `_initializeUI()` ? a constructor? why you put function inside function?

Comment: @Cherniv - looking at the error the constructor should be `Walle`

Comment: I don't really understand why this is giving you an error.  At any rate though, you onClick method never actually runs - as it's never called.   What you should do is break it out into it's own defined function:   `private function onClick(e:Event):void {`  and then add a click listener in your constructor or wherever you need to:   `this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);`

Comment: Is this AS3 or AS2?   if AS2, then it's probably because `onClick` is a reserved function name that I think needs to be top level on your class (not an anonymous function within the scope of another function)

Answer (score 0):

**Actionscript 3** doesn't admit nested functions. If you are using **AS2**, be sure the project is set with the right **configuration**.